# filtering VS code meta variables in the VARIABLES window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

is there a way to filter the data inspection output? It shows so many meta traits of each variable that its hard to find the actual values that the variable holds. It seems you can edit the debug configuration json file, but I can't find any variables there that would filter out all the unnecessary meta variables from the debug view.

**Example**

For this example, I have a list of links, but instead of easily being able to look at each link in the list, I have to sift through all these categories of meta variables.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Variable names and values can be filtered by typing while the focus is on the **VARIABLES** section.

[image: Filtering in the Variables section]